# How can i use svg file in scss file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, sass

I have icon.svg in src/assets directory.

And I want to use this svg file in some scss file.

like this

```
select {
    background: url("/src/assets/icon.svg") no-repeat ...;
}
```

but it doesn't work. and i can see this error

```
ERROR in ./src/components/atoms/Common/Dropdown/styles.module.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[4]!./src/components/atoms/Common/Dropdown/styles.module.scss) 5:36-104
```

i have tried these:

```
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;, /src/assets/icon.svg")
background: url(`data:image/svg+xml;, ${/src/assets/icon.svg}`)
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;" + "/src/assets/icon.svg")
```

and finally i solved this problem to this

```
 background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='18.258' height='10.164' viewBox='0 0 18.258 10.164'%3E%3Cg id='dropdown_icon' transform='translate(1.06 1.061)'%3E%3Cpath id='dropdown_icon-2' data-name='dropdown_icon' d='M-.09.18,8.264,8.371-.09,16.316' transform='translate(16.316 0.09) rotate(90)' fill='none' stroke='%23333d4b' strokeLinecap='round' strokeLinejoin='round' strokeWidth='1.5' /%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E")
```

but i don't want this. i want short code with using my svg file.

How can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a **webpack error**. Try appropriate **svg loaders** like:  [svg-url-loader](https://github.com/bhovhannes/svg-url-loader#in-css-with-webpackconfigjs-below).
Good luck!

Comment: Thx for your help ! I solved this problem with svg url loader thx

Comment: No problem.. happy for you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with the same url.

I think you can use (/assets/icon.svg).
try this:

```
.select {
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  background-image: url('/assets/icon.svg');
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: i got same error like this..
`ERROR in ./src/components/atoms/Common/Dropdown/styles.module.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[8].use[4]!./src/components/atoms/Common/Dropdown/styles.module.scss) 5:36-94`

Comment: if it is possible، one more time try the address without src. '/assets/icon.svg'

Comment: Thx for your help ! I solved this problem with svg url loader thx

Comment: @KNamuuu Great, good luck^_^